# native-base thumbnail not accepting the image source

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using native-base to show the the Thumbnail source, I am getting  error

```
Error: The <Image> component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on the top of the image, consider using the <ImageBackground> component or absolute positioning.
```

This is the error I have tried:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import { Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Body, Left, Right, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

class CardComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardItem>
                    <Left>
                        <Thumbnail source={require('../assets/me.png')}>
                            <Body>
                                <Text>Username</Text>
                                <Text note>August 29, 2018</Text>
                            </Body>
                        </Thumbnail>
                    </Left>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You Cannot have <Body> tags in side the <Thumbnail> tags

Comment: Thumbnail is React Native Image. You cannot have children for Image, so if you want to wrap text with Thumbnail, replace it with ImageBackground and apply Thumbnail style yourself

Answer (score 3):

Try this, this will work for you.

```
<Card>
   <CardItem>
       <Left>
          <Thumbnail source={require('../assets/me.png')}/>
             <Body>
                 <Text>Username</Text>
                 <Text note>August 29, 2018</Text>
             </Body>
      </Left>
   </CardItem>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ImageBackground>` Tag for appending a your Text over a Image.

Refer this [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#background-image-via-nesting)